# Specific Domain SQL Query result incorrect

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, automation

I am trying to pull list of emails for a particular domain (which is aproblematic domain) and somehow my results does not make a sense--meaning that I'm getting way less than expected.  To further test, I plugged in one JOBID that I know has 5 emails that were for this domain but only one is showing up.

```
select --distinct  
       w.domain
      , w.Month_no
      , w.Month_name
      , w.Year_no
      , w.jobID
      , w.id_email
      , w.EmailAddress
      , case when w.id_email_sent   is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as flag_sent
      , case when w.id_email_bounce is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as flag_bounce
      , case when w.id_email_open   is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end as flag_open
from(select  
          se.subscriberkey    as id_email_sent 
          , b.subscriberkey   as id_email_bounce  
          , o.subscriberkey   as id_email_open
          , se.jobID  
          , DATEPART(YEAR, se.EventDate)  as Year_no 
          , DATEPART(MONTH, se.EventDate) as Month_no 
          , DATENAME(MONTH, se.EventDate) as Month_name
          , se.domain
          , u.EmailAddress
          , u.subscriberkey as id_email 
    from ent._SENT se  
    join ent._SUBSCRIBERS u on u.subscriberid  = se.subscriberid  
    left join ent._BOUNCE b on b.subscriberid  = se.subscriberid  
                           and b.jobid         = se.jobid  
                           and b.batchid       = se.batchid 
                           and b.listid        = se.listid   
    left join ent._OPEN o   on o.subscriberid  = se.subscriberid 
                           and o.jobid         = se.jobid  
                           and o.batchid       = se.batchid 
                           and o.listid        = se.listid   
   where u.domain = 'domain.com'
     and se.jobID = 22725940
 )w 
where 1=1
```

[image: Target DE Fields]

Target DE Fields:

Comment: Why are you using the `ent` prefix for sent, bounce and open? And why the `where` clause at the end?

Comment: @zuzannamj  - My initial goal was to query entire enterprise not specific business unit that is why I have the ENT. prefix.  And, I'm running this on child business unit not in the parent. As for the WHERE at the end, it is just a place holder but should not make any difference--in fact, all my other codes have that.

Comment: @zuzannamj -- Figured out.  It was because I made my DOMAIN field Primary Key in the DE.   I just cannot believe that I overlooked this.  I made the PK: Domain, emailAddress, Subscriberkey (id_email) and worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOMAIN` field was my Primary Key in the DE. I made these fields as PK: `Domain, emailAddress, Subscriberkey (id_email)` and everything worked well after making these changes.